# Second pair of matching birthdays

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

The "birthday problem" is well-known and well-studied.  There are many versions of it and many questions one might ask.  For example, "how many people do we need in a room to obtain at least a 50% chance that some pair shares a birthday?"  (Answer: 23)

Another is this: "Given $M$ bins, what is the expected number of balls I must toss uniformly at random into bins before some bin will contain 2 balls?"  (Answer: $\sqrt{M \pi/2} +2/3$)

Here is my question: what is the expected number of balls I must toss into $M$ bins to get two  collisions?  More precisely, how many expected balls must I toss to obtain the event "ball lands in occupied bin" twice?

I need an answer for very large $M$, so solutions including summations are not helpful.

---

Silly Observation:

The birthday problem predicts we need about 25 US Presidents for them to share a birthday.  It actually took 28 presidents to happen (Harding and Polk were both born on Nov 2).  We see from the answers below that after about 37 US Presidents we should have a 2nd collision.  However Obama is the 43rd and it still hasn't happened (nor would it have happened if McCain had won or Romney had won; nor will it happen if H. Clinton wins in 2016).

Comment: Interesting. So a second collision occurs when a ball lands in a bin with either one or two other balls in it. That might be an extra challenge.

Comment: When you go to multiple collisions, there are more ways in which the event can happen. To be precise, is it correct that you're looking for the balls to toss until "either two bins have two balls each, or one bin has three balls"? Or only the former?

Comment: My statement is "ball lands in an occupied bin" twice; that would encompass both or your scenarios.  (Restricting to either of your two sub-cases would be interesting problems as well... I would be happy to see a solution to any of them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll first write down the exact answer (summation included), and then various approximations.

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of balls after which the second collision occurs. We want $E[X]$. As $X$ [takes only non-negative integer values, its expectation is](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Expected_value&oldid=555968266#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values)
$$E[X] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Pr(X \ge n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Pr(X > n)$$

The probability $\Pr(X > n)$ is the probability that after $n$ balls are thrown into the $m$ bins, the number of collisions is either $0$ or $1$. The probability of $0$ collisions is, as in the classical birthday problem, $\dfrac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)}{m^n}$. The probability of exactly one collision can be calculated as follows: for this to happen, some pair of balls must go to the same bin, after which the other $n-2$ balls must go to the other $m-1$ bins without collision, so the probability of this is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{2} m \frac{1}{m^2} \frac{(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-n+2)}{m^{n-2}} = \binom{n}{2} \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-n+2)}{m^n}$. Note that this is precisely $\binom{n}{2} \frac{1}{m-n+1}$ times the probability of $0$ collisions.

For the classical birthday problem, the same analysis as above gave that the expected number of balls until collision (call this random variable $Y$) is

$$
\begin{align}
E[Y] 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)}{m^n} \\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac{m-1}{m} + \frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{m^2} + \frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{m^3} + \dots
\end{align}$$

The asymptotic expansion of this sum, related to Ramanujan's Q-function, is [known to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people) 
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi m}{2}} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{12}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2m}} - \frac{4}{135m} + \dots$$

In our case, the expected number of balls until two collisions is the old sum, plus additionally the sum of the terms coming from the probabilities of having exactly one collision: it is
$$
\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)}{m^n} +  \binom{n}{2} \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-n+2)}{m^n} \right) \\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac{m-1}{m} + \frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{m^2} + \frac{(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)}{m^3} + \dots\\
&\phantom{=1+1} + \frac{1}{m} + 3\frac{(m-1)}{m^2} + 6\frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{m^3} + \dots
\end{align}
$$

That's the exact expression; now for the approximations.

---

One trivial fact we can prove rigorously is that $E[Y] < E[X] < 2E[Y]$. The former inequality is from the fact that the second collision can only happen after the first one, so $X \ge Y$. The second inequality is from the fact that after the first collision if we clear all the bins and wait for a collision to happen again from scratch, the second collision can only take longer than in the normal case. So
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi m}{2}} < E[X] < \sqrt{2\pi m}$$

---

One avenue of approximation is to instead calculate the "median" $X$, as Ross Millikan's answer does: find the number of balls $n$ for which the probability of $0$ or $1$ collisions is $\frac{1}{2}$. The expected value of $X$ will be around this. (And also strictly more than half of this $n$, because we have $E[X] \ge n \Pr(X \ge n) = \frac{n}{2}$.)

His answer already gives one way, here is another. From the expression we calculated above for the probability, we want $n$ such that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12
&= \frac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)}{m^n} +  \binom{n}{2} \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-n+2)}{m^n} \\
&= \left(\frac{m-n+1}{m} + \binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{m} \right) \frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-n+2)}{m^{n-1}} \\
&= \left(\frac{m-n+1}{m} + \binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{m} \right)
\left(1 - \frac1m \right) \left(1 - \frac2m \right) \cdot \dots \cdot \left(1 - \frac{n-2}m \right) \\
&\approx \left(1 + \frac{n^2}{2m} \right)
e^{-1/m} e^{-2/m} e^{-3/m} \dots e^{-(n-2)/m} \\
&\approx \left(1 + \frac{n^2}{2m} \right) e^{-n^2/2m} \\
\end{align}$$
which gives exactly the same approximation $\frac{n^2}{2m} \approx 1.678$ as in Ross Millikan's answer! Specifically, it gives $E[X] \approx 1.83\sqrt{m}$.

---

Another approximation is to use $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$ and assume that $Y$ (the time of the first collision) is concentrated about its mean. After the first collision happens (after $Y$ balls), there are $Y-1$ nonempty bins, so about a fraction $\frac{Y}{m}$ of the bins are nonempty and a fraction $1 - \frac{Y}{m}$ of the bins are empty. The second collision happens when either a ball lands into one of the currently occupied bins, or a ball lands for the second time into one of the bins not yet occupied. The former is much more likely to happen first than the latter. The expected time that the former takes is $\dfrac1{Y/m}$, as it's a geometric distribution (like tossing a coin that has probability $\frac{Y}{m}$ of heads, until heads comes up). So 
$$E[X] \approx E\left[Y + \frac{m}{Y}\right] $$
which if $Y$ is strongly concentrated around $\sqrt{\frac{\pi m}{2}}$, will be 
$$E[X] \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi m}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{2m}{\pi}} = \sqrt{m}\left( \sqrt{\frac{\pi}2} + \sqrt{\frac2\pi} \right)$$
which ($E[X] \approx 2.05\sqrt{m}$) is slightly more than the answer given by the first approximation.

---

We know that $E[X]$ is between $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{m}$ and $\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{m}$, so we know for sure that asymptotically, $E[X] \sim c\sqrt{m}$ for some constant $c$. We just need to find the constant $c$, and it seems the best way is to write a program for it. Here's a Python program that uses the exact formula above to calculate the value of $E[X]$ for increasing $m$, and prints $\frac{E[X]}{\sqrt{m}}$:

```
import math

def x(m):
    ans = 2
    term = 1
    other_term = 1.0 / m
    for n in range(2, m + 2):
        term *= (m - (n - 1.0))  / m
        other_term *= (m - (n - 2.0)) / m
        ans += term + (n * (n - 1) * other_term) / 2
    return ans

m = 1
while True:
    m *= 2
    n = x(m)
    print m, n, n / math.sqrt(m)
```

which prints (among other things):

```
...
16777216 7701.36209791 1.88021535594
33554432 10890.956487 1.88014384413
67108864 15401.7241385 1.88009327862
134217728 21780.9129334 1.88005752389
...
```

so $c \approx 1.88$ or $E[X] \approx 1.88\sqrt{m}$ seems to be the true statement.

---

We can say more about birthdays specifically ($m = 365$). With a minor change to the above program, for each $n$, we can calculate exactly the probability that $X = n$ (i.e., that it takes $n$ people until the second collision happens). This turns out to give the following distribution.

```
 n       P(X > n)      P(X = n)
 25      0.810743      0.023477
 26      0.785794      0.024950
 27      0.759490      0.026304
 28      0.731969      0.027521
 29      0.703384      0.028585
 30      0.673899      0.029485
 31      0.643690      0.030209
 32      0.612939      0.030752
 33      0.581830      0.031109
 34      0.550548      0.031281
 35      0.519278      0.031270
 36      0.488198      0.031081
 37      0.457476      0.030721
 38      0.427275      0.030202
 39      0.397741      0.029533
 40      0.369011      0.028730
 41      0.341204      0.027807
 42      0.314426      0.026779
 43      0.288763      0.025662
 44      0.264290      0.024473
 45      0.241061      0.023229
 46      0.219117      0.021944
 47      0.198482      0.020635
 48      0.179168      0.019315
 49      0.161170      0.017997
 50      0.144476      0.016695
 51      0.129058      0.015418
 52      0.114881      0.014177
 53      0.101902      0.012979
 54      0.090072      0.011830
 55      0.079334      0.010738
```

So as $P(X > 43)$ is still a very healthy $0.288763$, it's nothing to be very surprised about that there is still only one collision among the 43 US presidents so far. :-)

Comment: Very nice!  I have been working on this problem since I posted it and I followed virtually the exact same steps as you do above, but you are faster.  I just last night wrote the same program you did (in C instead of Python, but they're almost identical!).  I feel guilty seeing all the work you did on this... I'm doing this just for fun (it's summer after all!).  Cheers.

Comment: @Fixee: No problem; I also did it just for fun. :-) Cheers,

Comment: I have worked (unsuccessfully) at finding a closed form for the constant $c \approx 1.88$ that you approximate via your python program above.  Unfortunately the integral that so nicely turns into $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ ends up being much harder with the ${n \choose 2}$ multiplier.

Comment: @Fixee: Yes, I don't know of a closed form either. BTW, after running (a C version of) that Python program for many *days,* going up to $2^{38}$, gave the impression that the limiting constant $c$ should be slightly less than 1.879973, and this is suspiciously close to $\sqrt{\frac98 \pi} \approx 1.879971$, but this may be just a coincidence.

Comment: @Fixee: I've asked it as a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420923/conjecture-the-folowing-sum-is-asymptotic-to-exactly-9m-8).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $n$ people, and we want to allow $0$ or $1$ collisions only.

$0$ collisions is the birthday problem: $$\frac{M^{\underline{n}}}{M^n}$$

For 1 collision, we first choose which two people collide, ${n\choose 2}$, then the 2nd person must agree with the first $\frac{1}{M}$, then avoid collisions for the remaining people, getting $${n \choose 2}\frac{M^{\underline{n-1}}}{M^{n}}$$

Hence the desired answer is $$1-\frac{M^{\underline{n}}}{M^n}-{n \choose 2}\frac{M^{\underline{n-1}}}{M^{n}}$$
or
$$ 1-\frac{M^{\underline{n-1}}(M-n+1+{n\choose 2})}{M^n}$$

When $M=365$, the minimum $n$ to get at least a 50% chance of more than 1 collision is $n=36$.

Comment: I agree with you that this is the probability of obtaining 2 (or more) collisions throwing $n$ balls into $M$ bins, but I was asking for an expectation.  Every technique I know of requires computing a sum.

Answer (score 1):

We will change the problem slightly and make some approximations.  Instead of the expected value of $n$ to get two collisions, we will think about the value of $n$ to get a $50\%$ chance of two collisions.  They should be very close, as the probability of two collisions will rise quickly from near $0$ to near $1$.  In the single collision case, it is the difference between a factor of $\sqrt{2 \log 2}\approx 1.177$ and $\sqrt {\frac \pi 2}\approx 1.253$.  The approximation is that each pair of chosen elements has the same probability to match, $\frac 1M$.  This ignores the correlations between the pairs.
In this case, the distribution of number of collisions is Poisson, with $\lambda$ being the expected number of collisions.  The chance that we will not have two collisions is $(1+\lambda)\exp(-\lambda)$ with [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%281%2bx%29e%5E%28-x%29=1/2) $\lambda \approx 1.67835$ so we want $\frac {n^2}{2M}=1.67835$ or $n=\sqrt{2M1.67835}$ or about $55\%$ more than the number to get the first collision.

Comment: Well, I mostly understand what you did, but you approximated the median (tosses needed to get a 50% probability) rather than the mean, and they are not asymptotically equal for this problem (as you point out).  Based on computer simulations I've run, your 55% estimate isn't quite right: for small $M$ we need about 60% more, and for larger $M$ (say 100,000) it's less than 50%.  I don't think this 2-collision mean is proportional to $\sqrt{M}$ like the 1-collision mean is.

Comment: @Fixee: The "2-collision mean" *is* asymptotically proportional to $\sqrt{M}$, just like the "1-collision mean". This is because we can easily prove that that the 2-collision mean lies between the 1-collision mean and twice it. So assuming that $n = \Theta(m^e)$ for some exponent $e$, we can prove that $e = \frac12$ just like in the 1-collision case. Then the constant of proportionality turns out to be roughly $1.88$, i.e., $n \sim 1.88\sqrt{m}$. (See my answer for some calculation.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The reason my simulation made me believe the answer was not proportional to $\sqrt{M}$ was that--as your program shows--the multiplier starts above 2.1 and gradually settles to 1.88...  But your argument in your answer that it **must** be a multiple of $\sqrt{M}$ is quite convincing.