# Expected number of draws to get n number of one object

Tags: probability

I have been playing a game and came up with this question:

There are $n$ different object, and each time you randomly choose one of them.

One success is defined as one of the objects being selected $m$ times. What is the expected time to get one success (accumulating $m$ of any one object)?

In addition, what is the expected rate of success?

Please help...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about an expected time if there are no information about the length of time intervals between each selection.

Comment: In case you want to calculate the expected number of trials, look up: Binomial Distribution.

Comment: See Byron's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542200/expected-number-of-tosses-before-you-see-a-repeat) for an elegant expression for the expected number of trials.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some thoughts. You are probably interested in the multinomial distribution, since you can accumulate $m$ of any object, and not just $m$ of a single object.

So if $p_k$ is the probability of selecting the $k$th object, and if $X_k$ counts the number of times you have selected object $k$, then you are interested in e.g. $P(X_k=m,X_j<m\text{ for }j\neq k)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.